# Help with Infragistics ultragrid cells - manipulate text property?

Tags: vb.net, infragistics

I'm having trouble with an infragistics ultragrid using vb.net. I currently have a cell with the value "inner", however I want to be able to display a completely different string for that cell without losing the value. I understand that the cell has two properties, one value property and one text property.  The text property is read-only so I cannot simply assign a new string to that.
Any suggestions would be fantastic!

Thank you very much,
Adem

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your implementation, you may need to use a [ValueList](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/NET/2008.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.v8.2~Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.ValueList.html) in order to do this.

As stated on the [documentation for the UltraGridCell.Text Property](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/NET/2008.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.v8.2~Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.UltraGridCell~Text.html):

> A cell's Text property can't contain
>   something different from its Value
>   property. Setting the Text overwrites
>   whatever is already in the Value
>   property. It is better to set the
>   Value property directly so you can set
>   a typed object.
>
> If you need the text displayed to be
>   different from the Value of the column
>   you can add a
>   UltraGridColumn.ValueList to the
>   column that contains a list of text
>   and value pairs. You can use a
>   ValueList to do this even if you don't
>   want to make the column editable.

There are other ways you can go about handling this, but it depends on your scenario. For example, if the text/value combination cannot be changed during runtime, it may better suit you to just add a hidden column to the grid that holds the "value" that corresponds to your displayed "text".

On the other hand, if your scenario requires the user be able to choose from a list of items and you want to grab the associated value of a selected item, a ValueList is the way to go. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987167/combobox-in-ultragrid/) post offers a simple example of how to bind an UltraGridColumn to a ValueList.